# Byte array image into image url in response parameter java

Tags: java, image, url, bytearrayinputstream

I have an image converted into byte array in java, I want to set it into url that can be preview.

```
try {
        InputStream stream = this.minioClient.getObject(imageBucket, destination);

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int readNumber;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];

        while ((readNumber = stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, readNumber);
        }

        stream.close();
        logger.info("successfully loaded!");

        return buffer.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error: " + e);
        throw new RuntimeException("File Manager : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I'm using below code lines to get image bytearray.

Comment: Why not just link to the URL you're reading? btw it's easier to just do `stream.transferTo(buffer)` with recent (>= 9) Javas

Comment: Faster yet, just return `stream.readAllBytes()` (Java 9+).

Comment: @HaraldK ................ True ;)